# Change Bounding Box thickness in YOLO Darkflow

Tags: bounding-box, yolo, darkflow

i am playing arround with the YOLO darkflow (https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow) and I want to know how to Change the bounding box thickness of the predicted objects.

I use the following command to test a video

```
flow --model cfg/yolo-new.cfg --load bin/yolo-new.weights --demo videofile.avi
```

Actually the bounding boxes are too thick. When there are many objects on the image, i see only bounding boxes and no objects. So I want to know how to make the boxes thinner, eg 1 or 2 Pixels thick only.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

For darflow:
Change following line in file predict.py in yolo and yolo2

```
cv2.rectangle(imgcv,(left, top), (right, bot),self.meta['colors'][max_indx], thick)
```

to

```
cv2.rectangle(imgcv,(left, top), (right, bot),self.meta['colors'][max_indx], 1)
```

For darknet:
You have to change thickness of the box manually. So, search for following line in image.c file

```
cvRectangle(show_img, pt1, pt2, color, width, 8, 0);
```

and change 5th parameter `width` with pixel value

for example, if you want 1px box then

```
cvRectangle(show_img, pt1, pt2, color, 1, 8, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, Smit Shilu. I was already looking for this part but I cant find it. Did u found it in the darflow repo?

Comment: You will find cv2.rectangle in darkflow repo in files predict.py in yolo and yolo2. Just change parameter thick to 1

Comment: How to do that on darknet